# RealSQLDatabase file: accessing in Linux

Tags: database, sql

I have *.rsd file. By googling it, I found that it is RealSQLdatabase file. I am able to view it through text editors but it seems very cumbersome. Is there another way like Database browser or exporter to other file types?

Here's [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzo9X0mWSU-KRTRxSW1LbE1Fbms/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot of binary in there; I ran it through a filter:

```
cat stations-2014-11-28.rsd | strings >new-stations.txt
```

which leaves you a tab-separated file; this should import easily into database / spreadsheet or your choice.